# Creating a macro in excel that pauses at the stage I run VBA code

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I am creating a macro in excel.

I get to a particular stage in the automation when I need to run some VBA code.

During the automation process, I click on Developer and input the things that I need to input.

However, when I stop recording and try to run the macro from scratch it stops at the point of opening the developer tab and doesnt finish the process.

Sub CreatePortfolio()
'

```
' CreatePortfolio Macro
'

'
    Range("A2:H132").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-144
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Blank"
    Range("H1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = 11
        .ColorIndex = 11
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Name"
    Cells.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "B1:B132"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "C1:C132"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:H132")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("H14").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=126
    Range("A133:H133").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-168
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("I2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R2C8:R20000C8,RC[-8])"
    Range("I2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I133")
    Range("I2:I133").Select
    Range("J2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]>0,1,0)"
    Range("J2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J133")
    Range("J2:J133").Select
    Range("I1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = 11
        .ColorIndex = 11
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "IF1"
    Range("J1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = 11
        .ColorIndex = 11
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "IF2"
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$133").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="0"
    Range("A1:J133").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("SORT1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("K5").Select
    Columns("G:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("L:L").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("$L$1:$L$44").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Columns("L:L").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("M1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""",0,1)"
    Range("M1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M1:M4")
    Range("M1:M4").Select
    Range("M21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-20]C:R[-1]C)-1"
    Range("L21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Magic Number"
```

HERE IS WHEN I ATTEMPT TO CLICK DEVELOPER AND RUN THE VBA CODE

```
    Range("N21").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-24
        Range("O2").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]"
        Range("O2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O2:O20"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Range("O2:O20").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("O2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]="""","""",RC[-3])"
        Range("O2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O2:O20"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Range("O2:O20").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-27
        Range("P2").Select
        Columns("P:P").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Range("P2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""","""",RC[-11])"
        Range("P2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("P2:P19"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Range("P2:P19").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-33
        Range("O8:Y10").Select
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 16
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 15
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 12
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
        Range("O21").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Returns "
        Range("O22").Select
        Sheets("CODE FOR VBA").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-57
        Range("A1:A35").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("SORT1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End Sub
    Sub Macro2()
    '
    ' Macro2 Macro
    '

    '
        Cells.Select
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
            "B2:B133"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
            xlSortNormal
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
            "C2:C133"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
            xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Sort
            .SetRange Range("A1:F133")
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        Range("H6").Select
        Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Range("G2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]="""",RC[-6],"""")"
        Range("G2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G132")
        Range("G2:G132").Select
        Columns("G:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Range("G1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Missing Data"
        Range("H2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R2C8:R250C8,RC[-7])"
        Range("H2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R2C7:R2500C7,RC[-7])"
        Range("H2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H132")
        Range("H2:H132").Select
        Range("H1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "IF1"
        Range("I1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "IF2"
        Range("I2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]>0,1,0)"
        Range("I2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I132")
        Range("I2:I132").Select
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Range("B1").Activate
        Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$132").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="1"
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$132").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="0"
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
        Cells.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("SORT1").Select
        Cells.Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Columns("G:I").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Columns("I:I").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveSheet.Range("$I$1:$I$43").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        Range("J1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""","""",1)"
        Range("J1").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J1:J4")
        Range("J1:J4").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
        Range("J50").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-49]C:R[-1]C)-1"
        Range("I50").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Magic Number"
        Range("I51").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-30
        Range("L1").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-3
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Market Value"
        Range("L2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]="""","""",RC[-8])"
        Range("L2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:L49"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Range("L2:L49").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-33
        Range("L5").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=24
        Range("L51").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Returns"
        Range("M52").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-27
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
        Range("M52").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-30
        Range("M2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""","""",RC[-1]*(1+R[50]C))"
        Range("M2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:M34"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Range("M2:M34").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:M44"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Range("M2:M44").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:X44"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Range("M2:X44").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=0
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:Z44"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Range("M2:Z44").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-21
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:AA44"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Range("M2:AA44").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
        Range("AA2:AA44").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("M2:Z44").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
        Range("L56").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Equal Weighted "
        Range("M56").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-4]C="""","""",AVERAGE(R[-4]C:R[-2]C))"
        Range("M56").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M56:Z56"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Range("M56:Z56").Select
        Range("L57").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Value Weighted"
        Range("M57").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=SUMPRODUCT(R[-55]C[-1]:R[-53]C[-1],R[-5]C:R[-3]C)/SUM(R[-55]C[-1]:R[-53]C[-1])"
        Range("M57").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M57:Z57"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Range("M57:Z57").Select
        Range("R46").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
        Range("L56:Z57").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("SORT2").Select
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("A1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Returns"
        Range("A2").Select
    End Sub

The VBA code that I run is, 

    Sub SplitIntoCellsPerColumn()
    'updatebyExtendoffice 20160225
        Dim xRg As Range
        Dim xOutRg As Range
        Dim xCell As Range
        Dim xTxt As String
        Dim xOutArr As Variant
        Dim I As Long, K As Long
        On Error Resume Next
        xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Sel:
        Set xRg = Nothing
        Set xRg = Application.InputBox("please select data range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
        If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If xRg.Areas.Count > 1 Then
            MsgBox "does not support multiple selections, please select again", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
            GoTo Sel
        End If
        If xRg.Columns.Count > 1 Then
            MsgBox "does not support multiple columns,please select again", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
            GoTo Sel
        End If
        Set xOutRg = Application.InputBox("please select a cell to put the result:", "Kutools for Excel", , , , , , 8)
        If xOutRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        I = Application.InputBox("the number of cell per column:", "Kutools for Excel", , , , , , 1)
        If I < 1 Then
            MsgBox "incorrect enter", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ReDim xOutArr(1 To I, 1 To Int(xRg.Rows.Count / I) + 1)
        For K = 0 To xRg.Rows.Count - 1
          xOutArr(1 + (K Mod I), 1 + Int(K / I)) = xRg.Cells(K + 1)
        Next
        xOutRg.Range("A1").Resize(I, UBound(xOutArr, 2)) = xOutArr
    End Sub
```

But this code is inserted as a module already into the worksheet, So I just open the developer tab and click F5 to enter some arguments for the code to run.

Comment: It expects you to enter the values in the developer tab again. In order to solve this, edit your macro and change the values there, editing out the developer tab code it generated.

Comment: I'm a little bit lost

Comment: I have added the macro code if you could provide any insight

Comment: @ZarinaAkhtar,, better you edit your question and Paste the VBA code what you have recorded and mark the Stage or Row where you want to RUN the Macro. Also write the objective. ☺

Comment: @ZarinaAkhtar, it's huge one better write the objective,, what exactly you are trying through the Macro??

Comment: Ok, the macro is creating stock portfolios in excel. Its very tricky I have asked some people and they said a macro as I will automate this for every month!!!

Comment: I will simply add the data and then run the macro to create returns

Comment: And where in the macro is it not behaving like you want?

Comment: I have put a gap in the code with some text!

Comment: "During the automation process, I click on Developer and input the things that I need to input." Why not just use an InputBox() instead?

Comment: Hmmm I dont know what an input box is, I will google it!

Comment: @spikey_richie how would this help and why is it different that running the module?

Comment: Because instead of hitting a breakpoint and going into the VBA to change variable values, you can just throw them into an Inputbox and continue gracefully. You'd do something like strValueA = inputbox("Enter a string value for A"), intValueB = inputbox("Enter an interger value for B")